# app can't be opened because identity of developer cannot be confirmed

Tags: macos, codesign, code-signing-certificate

I am creating Mac os x App on 10.9 with Xcode 6. I have created Distributed App outside the Mac App Store using Developer ID. It works fine on my Mac, but when I test on other Mac with same configuration, It gives "app can't be opened because identity of developer cannot be confirmed" Message.
It should be display message with "open button" option but It didn't.
What I suppose to do to solve the Issue?

I have attach code sign and signing configuration image.

[image]

[image]

Is This Code Signing configuration valid?
Is it Possible to run app on other Mac by Xcode Configuration without "app can't be opened because identity of developer cannot be confirmed" Message.?

Comment: You should export the private key of that certificate in your Mac and import it in the other Mac.

Comment: ensure your .p12 in .cert are available in your keychain

Comment: I have generated certificate using xcode, so Xcode itself added certificate to keychain and I have manually check in keychain access.

Comment: See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31709087/failure-digitally-signing-a-mac-app-outside-xcode/32025478#32025478

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you did not export your private key

Maybe this helps:

1. on your Mac open Keychain app
2. go to Certificates
3. find your Developer certificate
4. click on the left triangle to expand list
5. select both sert and private key
   [image]
6. right click and select export
7. move and open .p12 file on other Mac

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have added .p12 in keychain of other Mac but same error.

Comment: Have you tried quiting & restarting the xcode, or restarting your mac?